# SKSpriteNode loses its physicsBody properties

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm using SpriteKit to create a game in which objects at the bottom of the map move.
The objects are crocodiles and coins.

The scene uses an NSTimer to that calls this selector:

```
timer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(generateBottomSprite) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void) generateBottomSprite{

int random = (arc4random() % difficulty+3) + difficulty-3;
if (counter >random){
    SKSpriteNode *bottomSprite;
    if (random>difficulty){
        bottomSprite  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"crocodile"];
        bottomSprite.size = CGSizeMake(70, 120);
        bottomSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = crocMask;

    }else{
        bottomSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"coin"];
        bottomSprite.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
        bottomSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = coinMask;

    }

    //create a crocodile
    bottomSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width,bottomSprite.frame.size.height/2);
    bottomSprite.name = @"bottomSprite";



    [self addChild: bottomSprite];

    counter = 0;

        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bottomSprite" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.frame.size];
            node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
            node.physicsBody.mass = 8000.0;
            node.physicsBody.friction = 2.50;
            node.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

        }];

}
```

}

The problem: all the physicsWorld's properties are re-initialized on each call to the selector and i must iterate over the children of the scene in order to re-assign them.

***Why are the properties get re-initialized?***

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the child node enumeration at the bottom is the thing you would like to avoid doing?

Comment: yes, exactly the problem.

Comment: Not sure if related, but I'll say it again: **don't use NSTimer in Sprite Kit apps**. Use the SKScene's update:/didSimulatePhysics methods to perform repeated tasks, or use SKAction runBlock paired with waitForDuration. Problem: NSTimer may fire at any time during the Sprite Kit update loop. NSTimer will even fire when the node/scene is paused or transitioning.

Comment: Thank u for the advice however, this also doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the categorybitmask before creating the skphysicsbody itself

```
bottomSprite  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"crocodile"];
bottomSprite.size = CGSizeMake(70, 120);
//add the following
bottomSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bottomSprite.frame.size];
///////////////
bottomSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = crocMask;
```

move all the physics settings outside the enumeration like so

```
if (counter >random){
    SKSpriteNode *bottomSprite;
int currentBitMask;
if (random>difficulty){
    bottomSprite  = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"crocodile"];
    bottomSprite.size = CGSizeMake(70, 120);
    currentBitMask = crocMask;
}else{
    bottomSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"coin"];
    bottomSprite.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    currentBitMask  = coinMask;

}

**bottomSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:bottomSprite.frame.size];**
bottomSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = currentBitMask ;
bottomSprite.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
bottomSprite.physicsBody.mass = 8000.0;//way too high
bottomSprite.physicsBody.friction = 2.50;//probably high
bottomSprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;//overkill, set only if critical


//create a crocodile
bottomSprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width,bottomSprite.frame.size.height/2);
bottomSprite.name = @"bottomSprite";

[self addChild: bottomSprite];
```

you also might wanna make use of the update method in the skscene and nstimeintervals to measure time till you pass half a second then call the generateBottomSprite method, it should be more efficient than using an additional NSTimer.

Feel free to ask if anything is unclear, hope this helps.